# Pool.map() with urllib (No multiprocessing?)

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib, pool, steam

I am trying to download around 150 xml-files from steam and save each of them into a different file. Now since it takes around 5 minutes for any way i tried before, i found a solution in here, pointing out, this should work with pool.map.
So i use this as in the code shown below. The problem is, that it still takes around 5 minutes, so i wonder if i did something wrong. Seems that the files are still not downloaded parelelly. I am really having some trouble with threading in python, still don't know how to use it properly and still don't achieve the goal i want to. The files are not bigger than 5kb.
I thought urllopen already takes too much time, but that's a problem i wanted to solve with threading.
(i took out the url-strings, since they are built from a lot of string, but assume i want to download 100-150 different files.

So what i am asking for is: Am i doing anything wrong here? And if not, what are other reasons, that this does not work, or is there a even better solution to achieve downloading around 150 files simultaniously?
Thanks in advance!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import urllib

def job(url):

    file_name = time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")+".xml"
    u = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    f.write(u.read())
    f.close()


def pool_job():
    pool = Pool()
    urls=[0]*150
    pool.map(job,urls)
```

Comment: I'd change `f.write(u.read())` to something that doesn't require loading the whole downloaded file into memory at once then write to disk all at once, maybe `f.writelines(u)`?

Comment: But it is quite likely that the code execution time isn't the bottleneck, have you checked that it is downloading at you max internet download speed? Is it possible your harddrive can't write any faster then it is? Those might be what's slowing down the program.

Comment: I already tested this. It was even slower before. I am running this script and downloading the files to an ssd with 12 Mbit. When downloading such small files the download speed does not go up to 12, but the problem here is, that this does not work simultanously, what i expected from using pool.map